# For Scale with screen size for canvas in unity3d, my sprites in Ui are pixelated when used for larger screens

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

For UI design in Unity, I am using Scale mode as `Scale with screen Size`. When I am using some image and render the UI on larger screens. Images are displayed as pixelated images.

I read about and `AssetBundle Variants` and want to use them.But I have doubt on how does `Screen Density` helps me to select correct AssetBundle Variant.

As per [this](https://material.io/tools/devices/) reference.

**iPhone** - 3.5 in, 320x480px results in selection of 1.0 (**mdpi**)

**iPad** - 9.7 in, 768x1024px also results in selection of 1.0 (**mdpi**)

So if both iPhone and iPad selects the same 1.0 (mdpi) version of asset bundle variant, Since I am using `Scale with screen Size` mode for Canvas Scaler in my game. Won't the images still be pixelated since its just scaled the same image for different sized screens?

I searched in google but unable to find a blog or any example explaining these things clearly. Am I missing something in the process of using `AssetBundles` or In choosing asset variant or preparing asset variant variant for Phone and Tablets differently..?

Comment: Don't use DPI to find the resources for your game use screen resolution instead otherwise you'll end up with a ugly pixelated UI

Comment: @buffalo94, could you provide any examples or blogs for reference

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have a link for what you asking for but i think it's up to you to say for example for High Definition resources the minimum resolution is this 1280x720 so all devices above the said resolution will use HD resources and all other will use SD resources

Answer (score 0):

You should export your assets in relation to the highest resolution as reference. 72 dpi is fine. Then to optimize the different builds to can use atlas variants.
I hope it helps ;)

Comment: Btw, while you are doing this you should definitely check all your assets are POT. If you want them compressed and you should.